# How to execute two java projects at one go in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project which do some processing on data provided in terms of CSV files. For testing purposes I want to create another separate application which simulates injecting the files on specific time periods and I want to make both applications run together so that the main application will get the files generated from the simulator application. But I want to keep the two applications totally separated.

Is there anyway to execute the two projects without calling one of them inside the other's code?

Comment: Pretty sure you can execute as many programs as you like just by right clicking the project and clicking run.

Comment: that's true .. but i want to do automated, i.e. : executing in one location (probably a third project ?) and both applications get executed automatically.

Comment: ah ok, I have written an answer below, hope it gives you some idea.  At least this is what I would do.  There may well be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a batch file that compiles and runs both projects.  You could also write a third java program that does the same as the batch file but using the Runtime class in Java to call exec commands.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third project that will launch both the projects simultaneously. :D